# What's the difference between "Magnitude Spectrum" and "FFT"?

Tags: fft, python, dft

I am particularly talking about the matplotlib's axes.magnitude_spectrum() function that plots the magnitude spectrum. Is this a representation of the discrete Fourier transform?

Comment: More information required?

Answer (score 1):

FFT (fast Fourier transform) is an algorithm that implements the discrete Fourier transform, in a fast manner. Both computes a "full spectrum" from a signal, which is generally complex. The amplitude spectrum is, up to minor corrections (scaling of components), the magnitude of the "full spectrum".